# Нейросеть всегда выдаёт 0.5

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Только начал изучать нейронные сети. При решение задачи XOR столкнулся с проблемой, что мне всегда выдаёт 0.5

```
import random


def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))

def dot(l1, l2):
    s = 0
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        s += l1[i] * l2[i]
    return s 


INPUTS = [[0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
OUTPUT = [0, 0, 1, 1]

weights = [random.random(), random.random()]

for _ in range(10_000):
    for i in range(len(INPUTS)):
        layer_input = INPUTS[i]
        output = sigmoid(dot(layer_input, weights))
        err = OUTPUT[i] - output
        delta = err * (output * (1 - output))
        grad1 = layer_input[0] * delta 
        grad2 = layer_input[1] * delta
        weights[0] += grad1 
        weights[1] += grad2 

print(sigmoid(dot([0, 0], weights))) # 0.5
```

Пытался с использованием numpy, тоже самое

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: А сколько у вас слоёв? Если только один скрытый слой, то `XOR` так невозможно реализовать. Есть интерактивные визуализации простых нейросетей, можете в них побаловаться, чтобы убедиться. Ну вернее я точно не помню сколько нужно нейронов и слоёв, но в общем `XOR` требует некие минимальные условия на кол-во слоёв и нейронов в них, которые у вас видимо не выполняются. Попробуйте увеличить количество слоёв и нейронов в них.

Comment: Вот это ещё можете почитать, например. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11589/creating-neural-net-for-xor-function Вроде иногда можно и более простой нейросетью решить, но много тонкостей есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было увеличить количество слоёв нейронов